# Using socket.io with net socket in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is there a way that i can use socket.io with net socket in nodejs ? so at the end i have main service that listen on port , waiting for connection (net socket) and main while listen to client's want establish connection using socket.io .

**Example scenario:**

- Main service running listing on port X for any connection request from client service .
- client's open web browser connected to the main service using http server
- in case of any incoming data from client service (server B) through net socket , the data will be sent through socket.io to connected client opening browser .

[image: Digram]

Comment: could you specify what do you mean by `NET SOCKET` ? Is it some sort of specific protocol?

Comment: NET SOCKET is socket connections , nodejs call it  The net module . https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nodejs allow to open 2 ports in the same running process . 
The following example shows :

- Main service listing on port 8124 for any incoming socket connection using net socket .
- Main service listen on port 8081 for any incoming http connection and client can receive any data from main service using socket.io

***Expressjs version : 4.13.3

socket.io version : 1.3.7***

**Example :**

**Main service**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var net = require('net');


var netServer = net.createServer(function(c) {
  console.log('client connected');

  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });

  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});

// main service listing to any service connection on port 8124
netServer.listen(8124);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/static'));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
server.listen(8081);
```

**Client Service (Server B):**

```
   var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(8124, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8081');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Great Job, but, what if server B was a telnet?

Comment: Hi, what does c.pipe(c); use for ?